# Library for parsing arguments GNU-style?

Tags: c, linux, arguments, gnu

I've noticed the basic 'style' of most GNU core applications whereby arguments are:

- `--longoption`
- `--longoption=value` or `--longoption value`
- `-abcdefg` (multiple options)
- `-iuwww-data` (option `i`, `u = www-data`)

They follow the above style. I want to avoid writing an argument parser if there's a library that does this using the above style. Is there one you know of?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[getopt_long](http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring04/cps108/resources/getoptman.html) will do the job, here is an example from http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <getopt.h>

 /* Flag set by ‘--verbose’. */
 static int verbose_flag;

 int
 main (argc, argv)
      int argc;
      char **argv;
 {
   int c;

   while (1)
     {
       static struct option long_options[] =
         {
           /* These options set a flag. */
           {"verbose", no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 1},
           {"brief",   no_argument,       &verbose_flag, 0},
           /* These options don't set a flag.
              We distinguish them by their indices. */
           {"add",     no_argument,       0, 'a'},
           {"append",  no_argument,       0, 'b'},
           {"delete",  required_argument, 0, 'd'},
           {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'},
           {"file",    required_argument, 0, 'f'},
           {0, 0, 0, 0}
         };
       /* getopt_long stores the option index here. */
       int option_index = 0;

       c = getopt_long (argc, argv, "abc:d:f:",
                        long_options, &option_index);

       /* Detect the end of the options. */
       if (c == -1)
         break;

       switch (c)
         {
         case 0:
           /* If this option set a flag, do nothing else now. */
           if (long_options[option_index].flag != 0)
             break;
           printf ("option %s", long_options[option_index].name);
           if (optarg)
             printf (" with arg %s", optarg);
           printf ("\n");
           break;

         case 'a':
           puts ("option -a\n");
           break;

         case 'b':
           puts ("option -b\n");
           break;

         case 'c':
           printf ("option -c with value `%s'\n", optarg);
           break;

         case 'd':
           printf ("option -d with value `%s'\n", optarg);
           break;

         case 'f':
           printf ("option -f with value `%s'\n", optarg);
           break;

         case '?':
           /* getopt_long already printed an error message. */
           break;

         default:
           abort ();
         }
     }

   /* Instead of reporting ‘--verbose’
      and ‘--brief’ as they are encountered,
      we report the final status resulting from them. */
   if (verbose_flag)
     puts ("verbose flag is set");

   /* Print any remaining command line arguments (not options). */
   if (optind < argc)
     {
       printf ("non-option ARGV-elements: ");
       while (optind < argc)
         printf ("%s ", argv[optind++]);
       putchar ('\n');
     }

   exit (0);
 }
```

Comment: But if you don't have libc ...

Answer (score 4):

GNU provides [`getopt_long`](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options), though they actually recommend `argp`. Check out the GNU libc manual [entry on parsing arguments](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html#Parsing-Program-Arguments).

Comment: But that is part libc and not a standalone library.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel The question explicitly mentions GNU-style, so I'm not sure that's a problem.

Comment: Hank:  OP asked for library in the title, it is not clear if he can and wants to access libc.  If on Linux, he's fine. If he wants a portable standalone library, then your answer doesn't help.  But only the OP can tell :)

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel somewhere there is a standalone implementation of GNU getopt... I think there's one as part of GNUWin32, among other projects

Comment: Yes, I used to to use that too, esp. for long-style arguments. But it seems to have vanished. These days, I like using [tclap](http://tclap.sf.net) which is a nice templated headers-only C++ solution that autogenerates the help, tests, ...  But it doesn't help OP who wanted a C library.

Answer (score 3):

http://argtable.sourceforge.net/

and

http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Parsing-Program-Arguments.html

Comment: Please don't just post links as they might become dead in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Back in the day people just packaged `getopt.c` and `getopt.h` with their sources.

Here is a [Google Code query](http://www.google.com/codesearch?as_q=&btnG=Search+Code&hl=en&as_lang=c&as_license_restrict=i&as_license=gpl&as_package=&as_filename=getopt.c&as_case=) for it. You could use that if you do not want to depend on GNU libc because you may need this on a different OS.  But if you're on Linux then libc already gives it to you as the other answers suggested.

Comment: The link to Google Code query is dead.

Comment: Google Code was taken down by Google a year or two ago.

Answer (score 1):

Google has open sourced the [google-gflags](http://code.google.com/p/google-gflags/) library, a command line flag parsing library..

AFAIK, it doesn't provide a "long and short" version of each flag (so you can't combine in multiple options "-aeiou"), but it's trivial to use and doesn't require a centralized list of flags.