# Vector arguments in TCLAP

Tags: c++, string, command-line, vector

Is it possible to allow passing a series of values, using TCLAP? My aim is to avoid

```
prog --opt 1 --opt 2 --opt 3
```

and have

```
prog --opt 1 2 3
```

instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so because in that case, it wouldn't be possible to discern arguments corresponding to `--opt`, and those corresponding  to unlabeled argument.

But I might be wrong, the best is to write some code to do your own test to see what happen. I didn't see anything in the doc about that case

Comment: But if I want to for example input and output several files in a command line like: 
./prom -f file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt -o file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt

How could I implement it with TCLAP?

Comment: I don't think this is possible because as I understand TCLAP logic, the last args are Unlabeled arguments.

In your exemple `file4.txt` would stand for `-o` and `file5.txt file6.txt` for unlabeled arguments.

You would say «okay for the last one, but is it possible that -f takes multiple args».
Again it seems that no, because the arguments order are interchangeable and your command line is equivalent to `/prom -o file4.txt file5.txt file6.txt -f file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt` and we have the same problem with the unlabeled args

Comment: And I might be wrong but my advice : test yourself the behavior of TCLAP, if you're lucky what you want is the default behavior. Otherwise check all the tests that are in the package source code of TCLAP, maybe there is one that fit your problem

Comment: I agree with you.But don't you think it's too limited? If we have several arguments in a command line and every argument has several values,and we are required to pass the values in the form `./prom -o f1.txt -o f1.txt -i f3.txt f4.txt`,then we can't implement it?Or we can implement it in some other ways like tell the library that string values seperated by spaces be treated as a string?

Comment: maybe it is possible with `getopt_long` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913767/library-for-parsing-arguments-gnu-style

Answer (score 2):

This may not have been the case when the OP was asked, but now there's an `UnlabeledMultiArg` that achieves exactly this:

```
//
// UnlabeledMultiArg must be the LAST argument added!
//
TCLAP::UnlabeledMultiArg<std::string> multi("f", "file_names", false, "vector of file names", cmd);
cmd.parse(argc, argv);

std::vector<std::string> fileNames = multi.getValue();
```

Full documentation can be found here: [TCLAP Manual](http://tclap.sourceforge.net/html/classTCLAP_1_1UnlabeledMultiArg.html)

Comment: It does not acheive that, because there is no flag associated with `UnlabeledMultiArg`, you have to just list the values in the end

`prog  1 2 3`